# How to copy some line of a text file by having a list of names

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I have a text file including 2,000,000 lines (`text1`) and I want to extract some of the lines just by having some part of the lines(`text2`).
Example:

`Text1`

```
seq1 TNS 23 45 67 81 92
seq2 trq 54 67 80 73 12
seq3 ewr 59 61 51 51 71
seq4 qto 54 94 93 92 02
```

`Text2`

```
seq2
seq3
seq4
```

I need to extract all Text2 inputs from Text1.

any answer will be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the matches into a regular expression, and run it through grep:

```
egrep 'seq2\|seq3\|seq4' Text1
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting this answer, but I actually think that @Utsav's answer is better, in that it technically does the same thing, but is easier to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to match from `text1` the lines matching `text2`

```
grep -f text2 text1
```

Here is the example I tried

```
$> cat text1
seq1 TNS 23 45 67 81 92
seq2 trq 54 67 80 73 12
seq3 ewr 59 61 51 51 71
seq4 qto 54 94 93 92 02

$> cat text2
seq2
seq3
seq4

$> grep -f text2 text1
seq2 trq 54 67 80 73 12
seq3 ewr 59 61 51 51 71
seq4 qto 54 94 93 92 02
```